# Django shared hosting setup

Tags: python, django, apache, fastcgi

I've really spent all my day setting up my Django application to run on my BlueHost shared hosting. My `.htaccess` and `mysite.fcgi` files are located in the domain root directory, not the account root directory, which means that I have a websites MySite.com which points to a `public_html/mysite` directory, therefore the two files mentioned above are under `public_html/mysite` folder.

.htaccess

```
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/mysite.fcgi/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

mysite.fcgi

```
#!/home1/username/myvirtualenv/bin/python
import sys, os

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home1/username/myvirtualenv/bin/python")
sys.path.insert(13, "/home1/username/www/mysite")

open("/home1/username/public_html/mysite/cgi.log", "w").write("Before try")

try:
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings.dev'
    from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
    runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
except Exception:
    open("/home1/username/public_html/mysite/cgi.log", "w").write(format_exc())
    raise
```

when I run ./mysite.fgci via ssh:

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
Status: 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

HTML here
```

when I access mysite.com in the browser:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
sys.path.insert(13, "/home1/username/www/mysite")
```

with

```
sys.path.append("/home1/username/www/mysite")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes a bit late but I hope it could be useful for others.

Next are my .htaccess and django.fcgi files.
These files are working properly in JustHost.
Note the difference in the first and last lines
I don't know if the configuration is the same for BlueHost.

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here is assumed that the .fcgi and the .htaccess files are in the same directory.
But in your case you can adapt the last line.

I am using a minimalistic .fcgi file (django.fcgi in my case)

```
#!/home/.../venv/bin/python
# DO NOT USE SOMETHING LIKE THIS #!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/.../django_project_directory")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "my_project_name.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```